# Using TIMER0_COMPB_vect

Tags: timers, interrupt

I'm trying to understand how to fully use the COMPB vector ISR of Timer0 on the ATMega328 (standard Arduino core). I realize it will make delay() and millis() not work but that's ok by me. I've setup some test code that *should* output a 244Hz signal on D4 and 488Hz on D5 (note, this is running at 8MHz). But D5 (COMPB) is always what D4 (COMPA) is. Any thoughts? Code below:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile bool stateA = false;
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    if (stateA)
        PORTD |= _BV(PIND4);
    else
        PORTD &= ~(_BV(PIND4));

    stateA = !stateA;
}

volatile bool stateB = false;
ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
{
    if (stateB)
        PORTD |= _BV(PIND5);
    else
        PORTD &= ~(_BV(PIND5));

    stateB = !stateB;
}

void setup()
{
    DDRD |= _BV(PIND4) | _BV(PIND5); 

    //set timer0 interrupt at 2kHz
    TCCR0A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
    TCCR0B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
    TCNT0 = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
    // set compare match register for 2khz increments
    OCR0A = 255;//244Hz
    OCR0B = 127;//488Hz
    // turn on CTC mode
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
    // Set CS01 and CS00 bits for 64 prescaler
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
    // enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0B) | (1 << OCIE0A);

    interrupts();

}
```

**Update:** After thinking about it, I'm realizing that it's not that I need two separate frequencies (though I just kinda wanted to know how, so this is good stuff) but I just need two separate interrupts, only using Timer0 (1 & 2 are already in use elsewhere). They can be the same frequency, most likely. I probably *could* put all the functionality I need in the same TIMER0_COMPA_vect, however I was trying to use that in a library I was writing and was trying to keep the functionality separate... this may not be possible.

Comment: You could optimize your code a little bit by replacing `if (stateA) ...` with `PORTD ^= _BV(PIND4);` (exclusive or of this bit) and removing those `volatile` state variables.

Comment: I don't see the point why you would need 2 interrupts at the same frequency, you can do your stuff in the same ISR.

Comment: Because some of the stuff is in a library and I want to keep it separate from other logic

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. The timer always runs at 244Hz, and OCR0B only matches twice per period, causing it to have the same frequency but a different phase. What you need to do is set OC0B on compare match and clear it in the overflow ISR. OCR0A you can simply set to toggle on match.

```
TCCR0A = _BV(COM0A0) | _BV(COM0B1) | _BV(COM0B0) | _BV(WGM01);
TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);

 ...

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
  PORTB &= ~_BV(PD5);
}
```

Also, OC0A is D6, not D4.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match what you are saying to do... could you maybe clarify a little?

Comment: CTC resets the timer when it matches OCR0A. We set COM0A[1:0] to 0b01 in order to tell OC0A to toggle. For OC0B we set it in the middle of the timer (COM0B[1:0]=0b11, OCR0B ~= OCR0A/2) period, and then clear it at the end (via the ISR). This gives it twice the frequency of OC0A.

Comment: Sorry, but some code would be really helpful, I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: The code I gave integrates directly into the code you already have, simply replace the assignment to TCCR0A as well as the whole ISR.

Comment: As well as the overflow interrupt enable that I just added (since you won't have the Arduino libraries to do it for you).

Comment: Aaaand because I wasn't thinking, it didn't occur to me that a match on OCR0A would happen at the same time as an overflow, so I've changed the ISR used. It should now compile against the Arduino libraries.

Comment: So... I was thinking about my code some more and I don't *have* to have them running at two different frequencies. I really just need to separate interrupts. Does that make any of this easier?

Comment: @AdamHaile: You don't even need two interrupts, you just need OC0B to toggle twice as often as OC0A. My code takes advantage of the timer hardware to do just that, rather than doing it all in interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code did not set `TIMSK0` properly.

Instead of:

```
TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0B) | (1 << OCIE0A);
```

You should use:

```
TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0B) | (1 << OCIE0A);
```

Why? Because `TIMSK0` is already initialized by Arduino libraries before your `setup()` is called.

If you take a look at `hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/wiring.c` and search for the `init()` function, you will see that it contains the following lines:

```
    // enable timer 0 overflow interrupt
#if defined(TIMSK) && defined(TOIE0)
    sbi(TIMSK, TOIE0);
#elif defined(TIMSK0) && defined(TOIE0)
    sbi(TIMSK0, TOIE0);
#else
    #error  Timer 0 overflow interrupt not set correctly
#endif
```

With these lines, the `TOIE0` bit of `TIMSK0` is set, but your `setup()` does not clear it.

Comment: This shouldn't actually interfere though. Timer 0 overflow is only for the Arduino timing functions.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I think it is still preferrable to ensure you set all Timer0 registers properly. Timer functions are a bit complex and you may be bitten by some strange behavior you did not expect, if you don't care for it.

Comment: See update above

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after reading the ATmega328P datasheet again, I am not sure that you can use both `OCR0A` and `OCR0B` in normal timer mode.

In particular, since you use CTC mode, I think that `TCNT0` will be cleared every time its value reaches `OCR0A` i.e. 127.

Since you need 244Hz and 488Hz (exactly twice 244Hz), I think you can operate with only one of `OCR0A` or `OCRB0` and do the work in one ISR only:

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile bool setBothPins = false;
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    if (setBothPins)
        // D4 is changed only once (244Hz)for every 2 changes of D5 (488Hz)
        PORTD ^= _BV(PIND4);
    PORTD ^= _BV(PIND5);

    setBothPins = !setBothPins;
}

void setup()
{
    DDRD |= _BV(PIND4) | _BV(PIND5); 

    //set timer0 interrupt at 2kHz
    TCCR0A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
    TCCR0B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
    TCNT0 = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
    // set compare match register for 2khz increments
    OCR0A = 127;//488Hz
    // turn on CTC mode
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
    // Set CS01 and CS00 bits for 64 prescaler
    TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
    // enable timer compare interrupt
    TIMSK0 = (1 << OCIE0A);

    interrupts();
}
```

Comment: Just checked it on my UNO, seems to work fine (with double frequencies, as the UNO runs on 16MHz).

Comment: See update above

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to use the Timer0 compare interrupts without affecting the `millis()` and `micros()` functions. Simply set the compare interrupts to occur at 1/3rd and 2/3rds of the overflow period. That way they won't conflict with each other because there will be some time between each of the three interrupts (overflow, compare A and compare B). You can't change the frequency though because that would change the update of `millis()` and `micros()`. Instead, you could use software *post*-scalers within the ISRs, something like this:

```cpp
volatile bool     isr_t0a_flag = false;
volatile uint32_t isr_t0a_delta_time = 0;
#define           TIMER_0_COMPARE_A_POST_SCALER 50

volatile bool     isr_t0b_flag = false;
volatile uint32_t isr_t0b_delta_time = 0;
#define           TIMER_0_COMPARE_B_POST_SCALER 100

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  
  // Find out what Timer0 has been initialised to.
  Serial.println(TCCR0A);  // 3 = Fast PWM mode with a fixed timeout of 255.
  Serial.println(TCCR0B);  // 3 = 64 prescaler.
  Serial.println(OCR0A);   // 0
  Serial.println(OCR0B);   // 0
  Serial.println(TIMSK0);  // 1 = Timer overflow interrupt enabled for millis()/micros().
  Serial.print("\n\n");

  cli(); // Disable interrupts.

  //
  // Set Timer0 compare interrupts
  //
  // Clock frequency     = 16 MHz
  // Prescaler           = 64
  // Timeout             = 255
  //
  // Overflow interrupt frequency = 16 MHz / 64 / (255 + 1) = 977 Hz (1024 us)
  // Overflow interrupt frequency =  8 MHz / 64 / (255 + 1) = 488 Hz (2048 us)
  //
  OCR0A  = 85;              // Set 1/3rd phase shift for compare A.
  OCR0B  = 171;             // Set 2/3rds phase shift for compare B.
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);  // Enable compare A interrupt.
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0B);  // Enable compare B interrupt.

  sei(); // Enable interrupts.

  // Verification.
  Serial.println(TCCR0A);  // 3   = Fast PWM mode with a fixed timeout of 255.
  Serial.println(TCCR0B);  // 3   = 64 prescaler.
  Serial.println(OCR0A);   // 85  = 1/3rd phase shift for compare A.
  Serial.println(OCR0B);   // 171 = 2/3rds phase shift for compare B.
  Serial.println(TIMSK0);  // 7   = All 3 interrupts enabled.
  Serial.print("\n\n");
}

void loop()
{
  uint32_t t0a_delta_time = 0;
  uint32_t t0b_delta_time = 0;

  ////////////////////////////
  // BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION

  cli();  // Disable interupts.

  bool t0a_flag = isr_t0a_flag;
  if (t0a_flag)
  {
    t0a_delta_time = isr_t0a_delta_time;
    isr_t0a_flag = false;
  }

  bool t0b_flag = isr_t0b_flag;
  if (t0b_flag)
  {
    t0b_delta_time = isr_t0b_delta_time;
    isr_t0b_flag = false;
  }

  sei();  // Enable interrupts.

  // END CRITICAL SECTION
  ////////////////////////////

  if (t0a_flag)
  {
    Serial.print("T0a ");
    Serial.println(t0a_delta_time);
  }

  if (t0b_flag)
  {
    Serial.print("T0b ");
    Serial.println(t0b_delta_time);
  }
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
  static byte count = 0;
  count++;
  if (count >= TIMER_0_COMPARE_A_POST_SCALER)
  {
    count = 0;
    static uint32_t previous_time = 0;
    uint32_t time = micros();
    uint32_t delta_time = time - previous_time;
    previous_time = time;
    isr_t0a_delta_time = delta_time;
    isr_t0a_flag = true;
  }
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPB_vect)
{
  static byte count = 0;
  count++;
  if (count >= TIMER_0_COMPARE_B_POST_SCALER)
  {
    count = 0;
    static uint32_t previous_time = 0;
    uint32_t time = micros();
    uint32_t delta_time = time - previous_time;
    previous_time = time;
    isr_t0b_delta_time = delta_time;
    isr_t0b_flag = true;
  }
}
```